# API sending zip file as response, how to save the response to zip file and store it in server folder?

Tags: php

I'm sending a request to 3rd party APi which is sending a zip file as response. When I use postman I can use save and download option and save that zip file. But when I integrate the APi in my php code I'm getting some coded response like this:
[api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvhtY.png)

I want to save the zip file in server location as soon as I get the response from API. Is there any way where we can convert this response to zip and store in specified path?

Comment: That is the content of a binary ZIP file. Simply write it to disk: [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are directly getting zip file content in your response. You can directly save that response as a zip file.
Example:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newFile.zip", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $response_from_api);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

If it does not work, you have to study the format of your API response and extract the exact content from the API response and save it on the file system.